# Access to the path was denied. C# WebClient Download OSX

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webclient

I'm aware there are answers to these questions existing already, however they more relate to windows and don't seem to be relevant to this question.

To start off, this application was made in C# and Xamarin.Forms.

What I'm trying to do is download three files into a folder on the computer. The folder does exist, so it can't be that.

Here's the code; (links have been removed)

```
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.DownloadFile(new Uri(""), @"../../../ush/");
            web.DownloadFile(new Uri(""), @"../../../ush/");
            web.DownloadFile(new Uri(""), @"../../../ush/");
```

I get this while debugging;

> Access to the path ' ' was denied.

If anyone knows a solution to this, let me know. 
Thanks.

Comment: `DownloadFile` needs you to give a path to a *file* whereas you just give it a path to a *folder*. Therefore it assumes file name is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't giving the path to a file, just to a directory. Thanks to Sami Kuhmonen I was able to discover this.